# Country of Residence for Booking a Train Ticket for Intra-Schengen Travel

Tags: visas, trains, tickets, terminology, residency

I intend to travel to France from Belgium,I have a Long Stay (Type D) VISA and I have applied for my residence permit but not received it yet.

While booking a train ticket on Thalys via GoEuro.com, they asked for my country of residence, and I was wondering if this meant the country that issued my passport that I am a citizen (which is not a EU member) of or the country where I have currently have residence? (which would be Belgium)

Comment: Train ticket  from which company?

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to book through Thalys Rail on GoEuro.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your country of residence is the country in which you currently are a registered resident. That for you would be Belgium.